# GUI elements won't keep size and position

Tags: godot

I am trying to create a simple UI, but my elements won't keep their position and size.  Every time I run the app, I see something different from what I can see in the editor.

Editor:

[image: Planned out UI]

App:

[image: What I see, when I run. The sizes and positions are for some reason reset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you're transforming controls placed inside Containers. You should never move nodes placed in containers manually, except for animation purposes at run-time.

To place nodes correctly when using containers, look into setting the size flags (fill, expand, or both) and perhaps use more nested containers.

[This pull request](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/30623) will make this limitation more clear once it's merged.